# In direct exchange of RabbitMQ, Does it convey the message to all the consumers which are connected to that particular queue?

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq

In direct exchange of RabbitMQ, Does it convey the message to all the consumers which are connected to that particular queue? or only for one consumer though there are many consumers?

I followed [https://www.baeldung.com/spring-amqp-reactive]. There it says " Multiple clients can subscribe to the same queue, but only one will receive a given message".But in another tutorial [https://medium.freecodecamp.org/rabbitmq-9e8f78194993] it says some other thing.

Answer (score 0):

The type of exchange does not affect how messages are delivered to queue consumers.

If multiple consumers are subscribed *to the same queue*, each message will only be delivered to one of the consumers.

I suggest reading the RabbitMQ documentation, especially the tutorials, where these concepts are clarified.